# Using wars in jetty embedded, websocket getting no factory for upgrade

Tags: websocket, jetty, war

I have two wars that I am trying to run in a jetty embedded uberjar.  One of which uses websockets.  Using a browser, I can get responses for the two wars just fine except for the websockets.  When I drop the logging level to debug, I see the following errors. Is there a factory that I have not configured on my WebAppContexts?

2020-09-09 10:35:10.204:DBUG:oejs.HttpChannelOverHttp:qtp38997010-16: upgrade HttpChannelOverHttp@3627c323{s=HttpChannelState@42e23fe6{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=0,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} Upgrade: websocket
2020-09-09 10:35:10.204:DBUG:oejs.HttpChannelOverHttp:qtp38997010-16: No factory for Upgrade: websocket in ServerConnector@6073f712{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:9191}

Source:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector});
        
        // war #1
        WebAppContext portalContext = new WebAppContext();
        portalContext.setContextPath("/portal");
        portalContext.setWar("/path/to/war/file/app1.war")
    
        // war #2 (war with websocket)
        WebAppContext hubContext = new WebAppContext();
        hubContext.setContextPath("/hub");
        hubContext.setWar("/path/to/war/file/app2.war")
    
        HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection();
        handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[]{hubContext, portalContext});
        server.setHandler(handlerCollection);
    
        try {
            server.start();
            System.in.read();
            server.stop();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include a code snippet on how you are creating (and configuring) the WebAppContext for those war files.  As it seems you are missing some `Configuration` types and/or bytecode scanning.

Comment: Updated with sourcecode being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable bytecode scanning, at the server level.

```
Server server = new Server();
Configuration.ClassList classlist = Configuration.ClassList
    .setServerDefault(server);

classlist.addBefore(
    "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");
```

That will apply the AnnotationConfiguration to all deployed WebAppContexts.